# MegaCli: when did a drive fail?

Tags: raid, megaraid, megacli

Using `MegaCli64`, is there a way to find out when a hard disk failed?

I.e., `/opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -ShowSummary -aALL` shows

```
            Connector          : Int.Ports 0-3<Internal><Encl Pos 1 >: Slot 5 
            Vendor Id          : SEAGATE 
            Product Id         : ST31000640SS    
            State              : Failed
            Disk Type          : SAS,Hard Disk Device
            Capacity           : 930.390 GB
            Power State        : Active
```

and I would like to know since when that disk is in `Failed` state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check the adapter's event log to find out when the drive failed:

```
MegaCli -AdpEventLog -GetEvents -f <filename> -aAll
```

will create an event log  as text file. Check the file for messages regarding your failed disk.

Comment: Thanks.  This produces a very long log, the thing to search for (in this case) ist “FAILED”.